# How to output the standard out of a subprocess running inside emacs --script

Tags: emacs, subprocess

I want the output of a subprocess echoed to my terminal while in **emacs --script**.

I have this file called "printer.els" with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
(apply 'call-process "/usr/bin/printf" nil t nil (list "%s%d\n" "hunter" "23"))
(princ (format-time-string "%Y%m%d\n" (current-time)))
```

When I run it with the command "emacs --script printer.els", I get this output on my terminal:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50flim.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50git-core.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50psvn.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50w3m-el.el (source)...
20140904
```

I expected "hunter23" to be outputted before "20140904".

I am running Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 ("emacs24" "24.3+1-2~ppa2~precise1") and on Debian Wheezy ("emacs24" "24.3+1-4~bpo")

Comment: I sure would like to move this question to the emacs stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is message the output, which you get by directing it somewhere readable.
You have specified in your code that you want output to go to the current buffer, but that does not make sense when running in --script mode like you have it, rather your should choose a specific buffer and then message the `buffer-string` once it is complete.

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (apply 'call-process "/usr/bin/printf" nil (current-buffer) nil (list "%s%d\n" "hunter" "23"))
  (message (buffer-string)))
```

If you are going to be running a long process it may be best to use `start-process` and use a process filter to grab and print text as it is output.

Comment: Note that this will print the process' output only after it has exited.